# Buying kitniyot during Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I have tried, with difficulty, to find good Halachic information about *kitniyot* on *Pesach* for those who eat *kitniyot* (there's plenty of information for those who don't), specifically about whether it is possible to buy *kitniyot* on *Pesach* itself. In most years, I do buy before *Pesach* starts, but I have my mother visiting who has a very specific diet that requires much of her protein to come from beans and other legumes, and I realize now I do not have sufficient quantities in store.

I know there are opinions that require checking of rice 3x, for example, before *Pesach*, and others which do not require checking at all (but require removing foreign grains if these are found mixed in with the rice).  They base their decision on the superior processing of grains and legumes that exist nowadays, and the efforts of processors to segregate foods due to allergens.

On a related point, is part of the permissibility of *kitniyot* based on any traces of *hametz* being nullified as part of *Biur Hametz* on *Erev Pesach*?

Since there is a dietary need in place here, am I butting up simply against a minhagic prejudice (which doesn't actually apply to me, since I'm Sephardic) or is there a significant halachic concern in play? Is there wiggle room to allow me to provide for my mother's needs?

Comment: I don't know, but if it is an issue regarding her health, than you are typically allowed more leniency than otherwise, as you need to have food in the house. What I would do personally, although I don't eat kitniyot on pesach, would be to check that it has a hechsher and was not produced in a facility which processes chametz. For a better answer CYLOR, if they're Sephardi. If not, b'diaved Yalkut Yosef may have an answer.

Comment: Why would this be any different than buying apples on Pesah?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the halacha question, but I wonder if you could skirt the immediate issue by borrowing from (Sephardic, Jewish) neighbors?  Do you have any (and do they have enough to lend)?  Any chameitz in their already-owned kitniyot would have been nullified, unlike any you buy from a store.

Comment: Now that the OU has OU Kitniyos hechsher, order those particualr products.

Comment: I don't have a local Sephardi rabbi. Yalkut Yosef probably has something, but I'm not familiar enough with the work and my Hebrew is not good enough.

I think that traces of hametz on the apple could be easily washed off, whereas this isn't possible with legumes and grains in the same way. Also, there is the possibility (however remote) that an actual piece of hametz would be mixed in among the grains.

I like the idea of borrowing, but the kitniyot I need is pretty specialized (whole grains and legumes). I think the new Kitni line doesn't include whole grains or legumes.

Comment: Well, it looks like the situation has self-repaired. I appreciate everyone's suggestions.  Studying the Yalkut Yosef might be a challenge, but it's not a bad idea for next year.